How do I tell this to stop searching for the same $item when it gets a hit, and continue to the next
So, I have this code reading the contents of a CSV and then searching for said contents in a folder full of .csv.
This is my first time writing in PowerShell so please speak as if I am an idiot.
The code needs to pull back a hit, but only if the $status also matches.
How do I get the code to move onto the next item in the .CSV after it gets a hit? I have removed the file paths for security reasons, but I know they are fine.
    ##Region ForEach Loop 
#==============================================================================
# The variable array ($array) is declared and holds an Array of strings.
$array = Import-Csv '' -Delimiter ','
$results = @()
$logFile = ''
# This is a ForEach loop block.
foreach ($item in $array) 
{
    # This echos out the present value of the string in the array when the condition is satisfied.
    # `n - it creates a new line after the message.
    # This is a print to screen CMDLET [Write-Host].
    $A= Write-Host Searching for $item.Web_Reference
    $B= Write-Host Status $item.Status
    $A + $B

    Try{
    $result += Get-ChildItem -Path '*.csv' -Recurse | Select-String $item.Web_Reference -List | Select Path
    if($result.Count -eq 0 -AND $status -Match 'Despatched in Warehouse'){continue}
    $logMessage = $item.Web_Reference + " - " + $result.Path
    $logMessage >> $logFile
    $results += $result
    }
    Catch
    {
    }
}

$results

#==============================================================================
#EndRegion ForEach Loop


"but only if the $status also matches" - if the status matches what?

@MathiasR.Jessen If the status, in this case 'despatched in warehouse', matches what is being read from the .csv. Status being the column header.

You could avoid a lot of unnecessary disk access by testing the $status value before doing anything else - no need to search the CSV's if we don't wanna collect the result.
Once that's out of the way, simply inspect the output from Get-ChildItem ... |Select-String ... and then decide whether to log/collect the matching path - you can use Select-Object -First 1 to only ever grab the first result (if any).
# $array holds an array of _objects_ parsed from the csv file's rows
$array = @(Import-Csv 'path\to\input.csv' -Delimiter ',')
$results = @()
$logFile = 'path\to\log.file'

foreach ($item in $array) {
    # Write-Host simply writes to the screen buffer, it doesn't return anything - no need to assign any output to a variable
    Write-Host Searching for $item.Web_Reference
    Write-Host Status $item.Status

    # escape any special characters in the search term before using as a regex pattern
    $pattern = [regex]::Escape($item.Web_Reference)
    # copy item status to local variable for convenience
    $status = $item.Status

    try {
        if ($status -notmatch 'Despatched in Warehouse') {
            # if the status is not correct then we might as well skip to the next item immediately!
            continue
        }

        # this pipeline will return either 0 or 1 string, thanks to `|Select-Object -First 1`
        $firstHit = Get-ChildItem -Path '*.csv' -Recurse |Select-String -Pattern $pattern -List |Select-Object -First 1 -ExpandProperty Path

        if ($firstHit) {
            # we got a hit against at least 1 of the CSV files, let's log it and collect the results
            "$($item.Web_Reference) - $firstHit" |Add-Content -LiteralPath $logFile
            $results += [pscustomobject]@{
                SearchTerm = $item.Web_Reference
                FilePath = $firstHit
            }
        }
    }
    catch {
    }
}

$results

Note that for collecting the results, we now create an object with two properties - this way you can keep track of which reference term was used to find a given CSV file without having to inspect your log file!

May I ask why encapsulating Import-Csv into a Array? I already seen it before but I'm forgetting the reason.  Also: I'm APPALLED you'd use += to add elements from a foreach() to a array! APPALLED, I say my good sir!

@sirtao lol, upgrade to 7.5 ;-) I wrapped the Import-Csv call in an array subexpression because OP clearly wants the resulting value to be an array - otherwise they probably wouldn't have used the variable name array :)

@MathiasR.Jessen This looks much better! However when I run it, the status that is being returned is a non matching status. Also, it doesn't appear to update the logfile after I have put the path in for it.

I know 7.5 painted += red, but it's still 5 times slower :P And .GetType() on a Import-Csv result returns a Object array anyway so... I'm perplexed?

@sirtao 5 times slower than what? The relationship between += and wallclock overhead from reallocation is not linear, it's super quadratic in relation to the input size. Re: @(), try testing with a csv containing only a single row :)

as interesting it might be this is getting long, how does moving to chat work?

@MathiasR.Jessen Any ideas on those little issues mentioned above?

@GrassLooksGreener I don't know what you mean by "the status being returned". The output should be 1 or more objects each with a SearchTerm and FilePath property.

@MathiasR.Jessen That's another issue, the logfile isn't being created to be populated.

@GrassLooksGreener have you tried with an absolute path? Eg. $logFile = 'C:\path\to\log.file'

@MathiasR.Jessen Yes, I have an absolute path in place. It looks like there might be an issue with the array when pushing the content to the file. I am not sure what though.
